# Getting Feature Names

Tags: scikit-learn

Suppose I have 4 feature(names)s ['year2000', 'year2001','year2002','year2003'], used during learning with Decision Tree classifier.
How can I obtain the names of the important feature from feature_importances_since it directly gives me some numbers rather than the feature names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you put feature names in a list

```
feature_names = ['year2000', 'year2001','year2002','year2003']
```

Then the problem is just to get the indices of features with top k importance

```
feature_importances = clf.feature_importances_
k = 3
top_k_idx = feature_importances.argsort()[-k:][::-1]
print feature_names[top_k_idx]
```